# Swift delegate value is nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

Please help configure the delegate in my code. For the moment, I get the value nil.

**Here is the first class:**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var loginField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!

    extension LoginViewController: LoginDelegate {

    func checkFields() -> [String:String] {

        var result = [String:String]()
        if loginField.text == "" && passField.text == "" {
            CRNotifications.showNotification(type: .info, title: "Введите логин и пароль", message: "Укажите логин и пароль для авторизации в системе", dismissDelay: 4)
        } else if loginField.text == "" {
            CRNotifications.showNotification(type: .info, title: "Введите логин", message: "Укажите логин для авторизации в системе", dismissDelay: 4)
        } else if passField.text == "" {
            CRNotifications.showNotification(type: .info, title: "Введите пароль", message: "Укажите пароль для авторизации в системе", dismissDelay: 4)
        } else {
            result["login"] = loginField.text
            result["password"] = passField.text
        }
        return result
    } 
}
```

**Here's the second:**

```
    protocol LoginDelegate {
    func checkFields() -> [String:String] 
}

class SettingsRepositoryImpl: NSObject, SettingsService {

    // MARK: Authorization
    var delegate:LoginDelegate?

    func authorization() -> AnyPromise {

        let loginAndPassword = delegate?.checkFields()

        delegate? = LoginViewController()

        let login = loginAndPassword?["login"]
        let password = loginAndPassword?["password"]

        print(login)
        print(password)

        let url = "http://gps-tracker.com.ua/login.php"
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "login": login,
            "password": password
        ]

        let promise = Promise<Bool> { fulfill, reject in

            if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
            {
                Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        fulfill(true)
                    case .failure:
                        CRNotifications.showNotification(type: .error, title: "Ошибка авторизации", message: "Неправильный логин или пароль", dismissDelay: 4)
                        fulfill(false)
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CRNotifications.showNotification(type: .error, title: "Ошибка связи", message: "Проблема с интернет соединением", dismissDelay: 4)
            }
        }
        return AnyPromise(promise)
    }

}
```

**What should I add that checkFields() has no nil value?** I'm completely confused. I hope very much for your help.

Comment: You need to assign the delegate inside LoginViewController. Also               let loginAndPassword = delegate?.checkFields()
delegate? = LoginViewController() this is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are creating new instance of `LoginViewController` inside your `authorization` function, but what you should do it to create an instance of `SettingsRepositoryImpl` inside your `LoginViewController` like

```
fileprivate let settingsAPI = SettingsRepositoryImpl()
```

and then inside `LoginViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.settingsAPI.delegate = self
}
```

also you should change your delegate to be

```
weak var delegate: LoginDelegate?
```

and then delete this inside your function

```
delegate? = LoginViewController()
```

you can call `authorization` inside `LoginViewController` like

```
self.settingsAPI.authorization()
```

Comment: I want to call a function checkFields() in authorization(), but you But you wrote, that I called self.settingsAPI.authorization()

I want to get result of checkFields() in authorization(). Can you help with this?

Comment: @MaximMazhuga you want to call `authorization()` from `LoginViewController ` or from where?

Comment: yes, authorization() I call from LoginViewController

Comment: well then it would work now, you just should change everything, I wrote. since you set `delegate` to `self` inside `viewDidLoad`, `let loginAndPassword = delegate?.checkFields()` should work